# How to add the data when its already choose the name and not repeating

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I'm having a hard time in this code. its repeating when its already chosen and i want to add data in DB when its already chosen

When I click spin the randomizer will choose the name and that name will update his status to done and it will not choose when I click again the spin button.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Binggo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="app" onload="localStorage.clear()">

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Title is here</h1>
  <p>Sub details will be printed out here</p> 
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6"> 
        <img class="left-img card-img-top" style="width:50%; margin-left:25%;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="Card image cap"> 
        <h3 class="left-text" style="text-align:center;"></h3>  
    </div> 

    <div class="col-sm-6"> 
        <img class="middle-img card-img-top" style="width:50%; margin-left:25%;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="Card image cap"> 
        <h3 class="middle-text" style="text-align:center;"></h3>  
    </div> 



    <div class="col-sm-12"> 
        <div class="col-sm-12 less"><br> 
          <textarea name="remarks" class="remarkss"  style="width:50%; margin-left:25%; margin-top:5%;" placeholder="Enter your remarks here !" rows="8"></textarea><br>
          <center><button class="btn btn-primary send">Done</button></center>
       
        </div>
        <center><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="spin()">Spin</button></center> <br>
    </div> 


  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using `ng-click` but Angular is not imported in this HTML.
try `onclick`, if it fits with the way `spin` function is defined.